# calling function with pointer leads to segment fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

this is the first time I post question on StackOverflow. I am writing a piece of C++ code, trying to solve semi-global matching problem. But I got stuck in this seg fault problem for two days.

I have 3 files: main.cpp, sgm.cpp, sgm.h. In main.cpp, I create space for two 3D matrices later I will use.

```
  unsigned short ***cost = new unsigned short**[leftImg.rows]; // cost matrix W*H*D
  unsigned short ***aggreg = new unsigned short**[rightImg.rows]; // aggregated cost W*H*D
  for(int row=0; row<leftImg.rows; row++) {
    cost[row] = new unsigned short*[leftImg.cols];
    aggreg[row] = new unsigned short*[rightImg.cols];
    for(int col=0; col<leftImg.cols; col++) {
      cost[row][col] = new unsigned short[disparityRange]();
      // fill_n(cost[row][col], disparityRange, 0);
      aggreg[row][col] = new unsigned short[disparityRange]();
    }
  }
```

Then in sgm.cpp, I implement a function:

```
  void calculatePixelCost(unsigned short ***cost, cv::Mat& leftImg, cv::Mat& rightImg, int dRange) {
    for(int i=0; i<leftImg.rows; i++)
      for(int j=0; j<rightImg.cols; j++)
        for(int d=0; d<dRange; d++) {
       cost[i][j][d]=calculatePixelBT(leftImg, rightImg, i, j, d);
    }     
  }
```

When I call this function from main.cpp by writing:

```
sgm::calculatePixelCost(cost, leftImg, rightImg, disparityRange);
```

The program crashed down right here when calling it. Bellow is the error message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401ef9 in sgm::calculatePixelCost(unsigned short***, cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&, int) ()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJwkR.png)

I don't know where goes wrong. Is the pointer `cost` causing this?

Comment: Don't become a three star programmer. Use 1D vector and map `row`, `col` and `disparity`  to their 1D positions.

Comment: If you are really using C++ and not C, then for the love of your particular deity, *please* use vectors instead of manually managing your memory. `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned short>>>` is going to be a LOT easier to reason about.

Comment: This code is in serious need of refactoring. You are using so many naked pointers that I'm pretty sure no one under the age of 18 should be viewing this post!

Comment: Yes, the pointer is causing this!

Comment: You should create a single array of the size N x M.  You can access the slots by using the formula: `cell_address = (row_index * NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS) + column_index`.

Comment: Use a debugger and verify the value in the pointer is correct.

Comment: `unsigned short ***` hurts.

Comment: Unless it's a homework that specifically forbids usage of `std::vector`, you should be using `std::vector` instead of many-star arrays. This may mean you will have to unlearn some old (35 years old or so) parts of C++ and learn newer (just about 25 years old) parts instead. Don't worry, time you will spend on it will pay for itself.

Comment: Uh... I guess I know how ugly this piece of code is now. Thanks for replies. I will rewrite the code and make it clean C++ style instead of three stars way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down.

Firstly, the kind of matrix you're constructing is what's commonly referred to as a "rectangular matrix", whereby

- All rows have the same length
- All columns have the same length
- All floors have the same length

Which means there is no reason to use pointer indirection at this level.

So our first refactor:

```
unsigned short *cost = new short[leftImg.rows * leftImg.cols * disparityRange]{};
unsigned short *aggreg = new short[rightImg.rows * rightImg.cols * disparityRange]{};

//All of this is now irrelevant and unnecessary.
//for(int row=0; row<leftImg.rows; row++) {
    //cost[row] = new unsigned short*[leftImg.cols];
    //aggreg[row] = new unsigned short*[rightImg.cols];
    //for(int col=0; col<leftImg.cols; col++) {
        //cost[row][col] = new unsigned short[disparityRange]();
        // fill_n(cost[row][col], disparityRange, 0);
        //aggreg[row][col] = new unsigned short[disparityRange]();
    //}
//}
```

You'll want a function that will help you access the correct index:

```
size_t get_index(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k, size_t rows, size_t cols, size_t floors) {
    return i * cols * floors + j * floors + k;
}
```

So in `calculatePixelCost`, write code like this instead:

```
void calculatePixelCost(unsigned short *cost, cv::Mat& leftImg, cv::Mat& rightImg, int dRange) {
    for(int i=0; i<leftImg.rows; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<rightImg.cols; j++)
            for(int d=0; d<dRange; d++) {
                cost[get_index(i, j, d, leftImg.rows, leftImg.cols, dRange)] = calculatePixelBT(leftImg, rightImg, i, j, d);
            }     
}
```

This code will help you narrow down the problem. But we can do a little better.

See, you shouldn't have your pointers hanging out all naked and exposed like this. Children might be viewing your code!

Because we're in C++ land, the correct way to handle this kind of situation is to wrap things up in a class. And since you need a proper "3-dim matrix" object anyways, let's make a proper matrix class.

```
class matrix {
    size_t _rows, _columns, _floors;
    //We'll use a std::vector object so that we no longer see any naked pointers.
    std::vector<short> values;
public:
    matrix(size_t rows, size_t columns, size_t floors) :
        _rows(rows), _columns(columns), _floors(floors),
        values(_rows * _columns * _floors)
    {}

    short & operator()(size_t row, size_t column, size_t floor) {
        if(row >= _rows || column >= _columns || floor >= _floors)
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid access to matrix!");
        return values[row * _columns * _floors + column * _floors + floor];
    }

    short const& operator()(size_t row, size_t column, size_t floor) const {
        if(row >= _rows || column >= _columns || floor >= _floors)
            throw std::runtime_error("Invalid access to matrix!");
        return values[row * _columns * _floors + column * _floors + floor];
    }

    //We will not implement a resize function, as the logic of how it should work
    //hasn't been established. It's probably better to simply allow new matrices
    //to overwrite this one using the default-defined copy and move constructors.
    //void resize(size_t rows, size_t columns, size_t floors);

    bool operator==(matrix const& m) const {
        if(!(_rows == m._rows && _columns == m._columns && _floors == m._floors)) return false; 
        return values == m.values;
    }

    size_t rows() const {return _rows;}
    size_t columns() const {return _columns;}
    size_t floors() const {return _floors;}
};
```

Then use this matrix in your code:

```
matrix cost{leftImg.rows, leftImg.cols, disparityRange};
matrix aggreg{rightImg.rows, rightImg.cols, disparityRange};
```

As well as here:

```
void calculatePixelCost(matrix & cost, cv::Mat& leftImg, cv::Mat& rightImg, int dRange) {
    for(int i=0; i<leftImg.rows; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<rightImg.cols; j++)
            for(int d=0; d<dRange; d++) {
                cost(i, j, d) = calculatePixelBT(leftImg, rightImg, i, j, d);
            }     
}
```

See how much simpler that is to understand? Yeah, it's more work up front, but you'll have an easier time reasoning about what the code is doing and why it needs to do it.

There's still a lot of stuff that needs to be checked out. For example, your reliance on a triply-nested for loop is suspicious, and at the very least, should be better refactored. But that stuff is less critical to fixing your issues.

At least with this new code, areas where problems are happening should now be easily identifiable.

Comment: In the first cut at `calculatePixelCost` I think you need to remove a couple starts from `unsigned short ***cost`. and `*(cost + get_index(i, j, d, leftImg.rows, leftImg.cols, dRange))` is needlessly complicated. just use the `[]`.

Comment: @user4581301 Fixed. I didn't spend much time trying to fix that code, since I was preoccupied working on a better, more "proper" solution for the OP.